# Query only returning 100 records at a time?

Tags: database, queries

I am trying to export data from a database to a csv file, I am using the code below to retrieve the data from the DB, but it only returns 100 rows, how can I fix that?

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'educators';
$query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);
$query->order('title asc');
$queryResults = $query->queryAll();
$educators = EntryModel::populateModels($queryResults);

foreach ($educators as $educator) {
   //Write to file
}
```

Comment: Your code could be simplified by adding an array as a second parameter to `getCriteria()`, i.e. `$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry, ['section' => 'educators', 'order' => 'title asc', 'limit' => null]);` and then just `$educators = $criteria->find();` – in other words; you don't need the calls to `buildElementsQuery()` and `queryAll()` in this particular instance, and `$criteria->find()` will actually return an array of EntryModels so there's no need to manually populate those.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Craft imposes a default limit of 100 for element queries. To disable this you need to specify a limit of `null`.

```
$criteria->limit = null;
```

Comment: `$criteria->limit = -1` also works :) `null` is more clear, though.

Answer (score 5):

By default, Craft sets a limit of 100. Set it to null: `limit(null)`.